# Fetch (x,y) from a 2D Array where condition matches

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, enumerable

This is 2D array:

```
int[][] array2D = new int[7][];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    array2D[i] = new int[7];
```

How can I turn the following into a LINQ query, or use enumerable methods to achieve the same output?

```
var lst = new List<Point>();

for (int r = 0; r < array2D.Length; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < array2D[r].Length; c++)
        if (array2D[r][c] == 0)
            lst.Add(new Point(c, r));
```

EDIT - Solution based on @'King King's answer

```
var lst = m_boardArr.SelectMany((row, rowIndex) =>
            row.Select((val, colIndex) =>
                new { val, point = new Point(colIndex, rowIndex) })
                   .Where(col => col.val == 0)
                   .Select(col => col.point)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lst = array2D.SelectMany((x,r) => x.Select((a,c)=> new {a,b=new Point(c,r)})
                                       .Where(a=>a.a==0)
                                       .Select(a=>a.b)).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work: the c loop variable operates on the filtered row, and won't reflect the indices of the original array.

Comment: Lots of edits, but you got it right finally :) This is the most compact answer. I like this.

Comment: Can you please use better var names? :)

Comment: @Nayan the `r` and `c` follow your original code, I don't have any idea for other `mediate` var names.

Comment: @Nayan What about other var names? `a`, `b`? It's hard to name them semantically.

Comment: I did not use 'a', 'b' in my example. Can you tell me what do they mean in your example?

Comment: @Nayan to me, they are just `mediate variables`, `a` references the element in the inner loop, `b` references the `Point`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lst = array2D
    .SelectMany((innerArray, r)
        => Enumerable
               .Range(0, innerArray.Length)
               .Where(c => innerArray[c] == 0)
               .Select(c => new Point(c, r)))
    .ToList();
```

However, your current solution is more readable.

Comment: Your first answer works, but second isn't compilable as Point is structure, not a class. So, you can't type cast a null to Point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the `Select` and `SelectMany` that capture the loop variables into an anonymous type, then get those properties back later after the `Where` clause, thus:

```
var list = array2D
    .SelectMany((row, r) => row
        .Select((el, c) => 
        new {Element = el, ColIndex = c, RowIndex = r})
        .Where(thing => thing.Element == 0)
        .Select(thing => new Point(thing.RowIndex, thing.ColIndex)))
    .ToList();
```

EDIT: Bartosz's comment applies to this solution as well.  Unreadable!

Comment: Your solution gives almost right answer... actually, you swapped x and y. So, the list contains 'Point(y, x)' data. Numeric values are correct, though.

Comment: I think `LINQ` is something `unreadable` in many cases. The more complex the query is, the more unreadable we can feel, maybe that's because of it's `succinctness`.